# Rails model optimization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization

I have a List model below, it has a has_and_belongs_to_many association with recipients. The purpose of the method `make_recipient_lists` is to save a parsed csv of `numbers`(initial parameter) in this format `[[num1],[num2],[num3]...]`.

`add_recipients` work by finding existing recipients then adding them to the list or creating new recipients.

This whole process works well for small amount, 20k of numbers in 28minutes. However, the greater the number, the longer it takes exponentially, 70k took 14hours. Probably because it was checking for duplicates to a cached `current_lists`.

Question is, is there any way to make this faster? I am probably approaching this problem wrong. Thanks!

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base

#other methods above

  def make_recipient_lists(numbers,options)
    rejected_numbers = []
    account = self.user.account

    #caching recipients
    current_recipients = self.recipients

    numbers.each do |num|
      add_recipient(num[0], current_recipients)
    end

  end

  def add_recipient(num, current_recipients)
    account = self.user.account

    recipient = current_recipients.where(number:num, account_id: account.id).first
    recipient ||= current_recipients.create!(number:num, account_id: account.id)

    recipient
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. I have not tested this, but you get the idea.

```
  def make_recipient_lists(numbers, options)
    rejected_numbers = []
    account = self.user.account
    existing_numbers = self.recipients.where(number: numbers, account_id: account.id).map(&:number)
    new_records = (numbers - existing_numbers).map {|n| {number: n, account_id: account.id, list_id: self.id} }

    Recipient.create new_records
  end
```

Comment: Hi @Neo, I'm going to try it in a while but it looks really promising. Thank you.

Comment: Added a lot in the code but this helped a lot. Thank you @Neo!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use rails active_record query interface. you can use method find_or_create method for this: It will make your queries faster. change your method like this, and check the time difference:

```
def make_recipient_lists(numbers,options)
    rejected_numbers = []
    account = self.user.account

    #caching recipients
    current_recipients = self.recipients

    numbers.each do |num|
      self.recipients.find_or_create_by(number: num, account_id: account.id)      
    end
end
```

Hope it will help. Thanks.